# binding different tables from DB into gridview!

Tags: asp.net, gridview

how do i dynamically bind different tables from DB with different columns into gridview?

Actually, i was using OleDbDataAdapter to to join the SQL statement and put in a DataTable but my question is, let says, i execute 1st SQL statement and when i execute 2nd SQL statement, the data adapter will use back the 1st SQL statement. So, i was thinking how to make the data adapter to clear off the 1st SQL statement before executing the 2nd statement???

Comment: Can you give more detailed description what you want to do? Are you using SqlDataSource, ObjectDataSource or something else?

Comment: your question is not clear... can u describe more your qeustion....

Answer (score 2):

Here are three possible solutions from easiest to hardest:

1. Join the tables in a view and select against the view for your data source.
2. Join the tables in a SQL statement and use that as your data source.
3. Create a new bindable collection (probably a DataTable) and dynamically add data from the two tables to it. Use that as your data source.

Answer (score 0):

You always have 
dtbl1.Merge(dtbl2);